# BitBucket Server API Call For Deleting and/or Renaming Content

Tags: bitbucket-api

Looking here for an API endpoint to delete and/or rename a piece of content in a repository. I don't see anything relevant. How does one do this?
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in May 2017 Atlassian stated that it is [not supported](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/how-do-i-delete-a-bitbucket-file-using-rest-api/3887).

When looking at the [Bitbucket REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.10.1/bitbucket-rest.html) of version 5.10.1 in June 2018, it is still not supported.

There is a files endpoint at `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/files`, but it only has a `GET` endpoint to list the files in a specific directory of the repository.

There also is a `/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/browse/{path:.*}` endpoint. It supports `GET` to list the files in a directory of a repository and supports `PUT` to commit one file per call. However, `DELETE` is not supported on that endpoint.

The same goes for renames. The documentation does not mention the ability to do so with a REST API call.

Answer (score 0):

`/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/src` This API can be used to update or delete files.

From [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src#post)

> To create a commit that deletes files, use the files parameter:
>
> $ curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/username/slug/src \ 
>   -F files=/file/to/delete/1.txt \   -F files=/file/to/delete/2.txt
>
> You can add/modify/delete multiple files in a request. Rename/move a
>   file by deleting the old path and adding the content at the new path.

Comment: the link is not working. Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

A way I found to delete files using the API was with a shell file `delete-file.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

host=https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0
workspace=my-workspace
author="MY COMPANY Automation Bot <autobot@mycompany.com>"

TOKEN=${1:?'TOKEN: The first param is missing'}
REPO_SLUG=${2:?'REPO_SLUG: The second param is missing'}
BRANCH=${3:?'BRANCH: The third param is missing'}
FILE_PATH=${4:?'FILE_PATH: The forth param is missing'}

curl "$host/repositories/$workspace/$REPO_SLUG/src" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -F "files=/$FILE_PATH" \
  -F "message=Delete $FILE_PATH" \
  -F "branch=$BRANCH" \
  -F "author=$author"
```

Then just run the command to create a commit with the deleted file in the branch desired:

```bash
./delete-file.sh AAAAyyyy0000_my_token my-repo-slug my-branch src/file.txt
```

---

You can generate the token with client credentials:

```bash
curl -sX POST -u "$BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID:$BITBUCKET_SECRET" \
      "https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token" \
      -d grant_type=client_credentials -d scopes=repository | jq -r .access_token
```

Or, as my case, using python:

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import subprocess
import os

BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID')
BITBUCKET_SECRET = os.getenv('BITBUCKET_SECRET')

def get_token():
    url = "https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token"
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scopes": "repository"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth = HTTPBasicAuth(BITBUCKET_CLIENT_ID, BITBUCKET_SECRET))
    return response.json()['access_token']

token = get_token()

subprocess.call([
    "sh",
    "scripts/delete-file.sh",
    token,
    "my-repo-slug",
    "my-branch",
    "src/file.txt"
])
```